# StartOfLine and EndOfLine not working well inside Shortest

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

Suppose that I want to replace lines containing "b" with a new "XXX" line. This works as expected with regular expressions:

```
StringReplace["a\n_b_\nc", RegularExpression["(?m)^.+b.+$"] -> "XXX"]

"a
XXX
c"
```

The `(?m)` activates multi-line mode so that `^` and `$` can refer to each of the line beginnings and ends in the string. This is kind of cryptic so I prefer to use string expressions, but then, I get a different result:

```
StringReplace["a\n_b_\nc", 
    Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ ___ ~~ "b" ~~ ___ ~~ EndOfLine] -> "XXX"]

"XXX
c"
```

As a workaround, I can make it work like this:

```
StringReplace["a\n_b_\nc", 
    Shortest["\n" ~~ ___ ~~ "b" ~~ ___ ~~ "\n"] -> "\nXXX\n"]

"a
XXX
c"
```

but I would think that one should be able to use `StartOfLine` and `EndOfLine`.

What is going on? Are  `StartOfLine` and `EndOfLine` incompatible with `Shortest`?

Answer (score 4):

I confirmed with Wolfram support that this is not a bug [CASE:4214621]. This is what they said:

> I believe that Shortest is behaving as designed here. The reason seems
>   to be described under Details in ref/Shortest:
>
> "If several `Shortest` objects occur in the same expression, those that
>   appear first are given higher priority to match shortest sequences."
>
> "`Shortest[p]` may not correspond to the absolutely shortest expression
>   matching `p` if there are additional constraints elsewhere in the
>   pattern."
>
> We can actually verify that the desired answer is part of the matches
>   but it is being prioritized lower. For instance, consider the
>   following:
>
> ```
> In[1]:= StringCases["a\n_b_\nc", 
>           Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ ___ ~~ "b" ~~ ___ ~~ EndOfLine], Overlaps -> True]
> Out[1]= {"a\n_b_", "_b_"}
> ```

I find this information very useful, by using `Overlaps -> True` one can understand what is going on. The issue is the usage of multiple `BlankNullSequence` (`___`) inside `Shortest`. With this knowledge I can now use a simpler string expression:

```
StringReplace["a\n_b_\nc", Except["\n"] ... ~~ "b" ~~ Except["\n"] ... -> "XXX"]
```

> `"a
>   XXX
>   c"`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug to me. We can see what going on by looking this evaluation:

```
StringReplace[
  "a\n_b_\nc",
  s : Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ ___ ~~ "b" ~~ ___ ~~ EndOfLine] -> "*" ~~ s ~~ "*"]
```

> `"*a
>   _b_*
>   c"`

Clearly, the 1st `"\n"` is not being handled properly. However and strangely,

```
StringReplace[
  "a\n_b_\nc",
  Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ s___ ~~ EndOfLine] -> "*" ~~ s ~~ "*"]
```

works and gives

> `"*a*
>   *_b_*
>   *c*"`

From this 2nd result, we can derive a work-around.

```
StringReplace[
  "a\n_b_\nc",
  Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ s___ ~~ EndOfLine] :> If[StringContainsQ[s, "b"], "XXX", s]]
```

> `"a
>   XXX
>   c"`

Not very pretty, I admit.

Another sign pointing to `Shortest` being buggy. Evaluating

```
StringReplace[
  "a\n_b_\nc",
  Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ _ ~~ "b" ~~ ___ ~~ EndOfLine] -> "XXX"]
```

gives the correct result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I contacted support and it turns out it is not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the support that everything works as expected here. I would add to their explanation that the actual source of the differences in behavior of the `RegularExpression` and the `StringExpression` is that the latter always adds the `s` modifier which means ***dot matches newline***. We can check this by converting `StringExpression` into the corresponding `RegularExpression` (what *Mathematica* always does internally):

```
StringPattern`PatternConvert[
 Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ ___ ~~ "b" ~~ ___ ~~ EndOfLine]]
```

> ```
> {"(?ms)^.*?b.*?$", {}, {}, Hold[None]}
> ```

One can see the `(?ms)` at the beginning of the regex. It is easy to check that addition of the `s` modifier will break behavior of the regex described at the top of the original question:

```
StringReplace["a\n_b_\nc", 
 RegularExpression["(?ms)^.+b.+$"] -> "XXX"]
```

> ```
> "XXX"
> ```

Note that the OP's regex uses *greedy* quantifier `+` (what is equivalent to `Longest`). If instead we will use *lasy* quantifier `+?` (which is equivalent to `Shortest`), we will get exactly what `StringExpression` returns:

```
StringReplace["a\n_b_\nc", 
 RegularExpression["(?ms)^.+?b.+?$"] -> "XXX"]
```

> ```
> "XXX
> c"
> ```

`StringExpression` has no option to switch off the mode when `_` (equivalent to `.` in regex) matches newline. So the only way to achieve this is to use `Except["\n"]` instead of `_` (what was found by the OP).